# Is it a usecase for a factory pattern when loading configs in a constructor for an API call?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I have a class called **GatewayAPI**, which has to load configs from a file, when used. I first wanted to put the get_config() method in the constructor, but I don't like this design for testing purposes.

Now I plan to do a factory, which creates this GatewayObject. Is this a typical usecase for the Factory Pattern?

Second question: Is it enough to put a method called "create" in the APIGateway class or should the factory be independent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes this is a typical use case for the Factory pattern.

The point of a factory is to apply some set of complex logic to create and configure an object/object ecosystem for use, possibly accepting some parameters to refine/control that logic.

2. Singletons in code are generally a bad idea.

A class level method is a singleton. Later when you want two different pieces of factory logic, you can't because only one piece of factory logic is called `class::create()`.

This makes any sort of testing, particularly Unit Testing painful, as you cannot easily Mock the factory, or the returned object.

If this `create()` was an object level method instead, it is still a problem. The `GatewayAPI` objects now have conflicting roles. Is the object a gateway, or a factory to get a gateway? When you call `create()` and get an object back, is that the gateway, or a factory to get the gateway? How many turtles deep does this go?

3. Bonus round. The configuration for the `GatewayAPI` should be separate from the `GatewayAPI`.

As the factory is responsible for configuring the `GatewayAPI`, the `GatewayAPI` should no longer be responsible for knowing what that configuration is, before it is configured.

It is the factory's job now to know what the configuration is/how to obtain the configuration/be told the configuration and then apply it.